# Sudo commands take to long to execute after run VPNC

Tags: command-line, 20.04, sudo, vpnc

I'm using VPNC to connect to my company's vpn, and after start the .conf all the sudo commands on ubuntu 20.04 become slower, kill (or deactivate) the vpnc process solve this problem.

Comment: How are you connected? WiFi? What's your MTU? `ip link`. How much RAM/swap? `free`.

Comment: @waltinator tks for your time, but i found the issue. It was a problem at my company's vpn configuration directly to my user